# Linq : How do I test a List<bool> for condition where any one of its values == true?

Tags: linq

I have a list,

```
List<bool> MyList;
MyList.Add(true);
MyList.Add(false);
MyList.Add(false);
```

What is a clean way to use linq to test if any value is true? I tried

```
MyList.Find(SomeBoolean=>SomeBoolean)
```

but the result is weird.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try :

```
bool test = MyList.Any(x => x);
```

But you have to initialize your list before inserting anything.

Comment: MyList.Any(x => x == true);
Doesn't hurt to be explicit in this case IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Use Any

```
var anyTrue = MyList.Any(i => i);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to List all the `true` value

```
List<bool> MyList = new List<bool>();
MyList.Add(true);
MyList.Add(false);
MyList.Add(false);
var listTrue = MyList.Where(c => c);
```

I wonder, what is your actual `Class` because if you want to `.Find` is the same result.

```
var b = MyList.Find(c => c)
```

maybe you forgot to declare the `var` or `DataType`?

Answer (score 0):

myList is a list of bool

myList= getSelectedChannels();
List allTrue= myList.FindAll(a => a == true);

allTrue will be a list of bool that match the criteria (bool is true).  Now just say allTrue.Count to get the number of items in that list.